# ¿Qué función sintáctica tiene "atrapar" en la frase "Atrapar pelotas es divertido"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, infinitivo

Supongo que en la frase "Atrapar pelotas es divertido" , `pelotas` "es el sujeto, `es` es el verbo, y `divertido`, si entiendo bien, sería un complemento predicativo. Ahora, ¿qué función sintáctica tiene `atrapar` en esta frase? ¿Qué es?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde luego `es` es el verbo, pero no es "pelotas" lo que es divertido, sino "**atrapar** pelotas", luego le estamos dando a un verbo (en infinitivo) un uso que no es de verbo. ¿Es esto posible? **Sí**.

> El infinitivo en español ejerce funciones de SUSTANTIVO y por lo tanto puede funcionar como sujeto, complemento del verbo o modificador de nombre, adjetivo o adverbio.

Por tanto en esa oración "atrapar" funciona como un sustantivo, igual que "pelotas", y el sujeto es "atrapar pelotas" y no solo "pelotas".

Fuente: [Usos del infinitivo](http://fis.ucalgary.ca/AVal/505/AGUsosInfinitivo.html)

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice Diego, "atrapar" es un verbo en infinitivo y, como tal, tiene valor nominal y puede funcionar como sujeto. Ahora bien, en la oración en cuestión "atrapar" es el NÚCLEO de ese sujeto.

En un análisis sintáctico más minucioso, es importante señalar que, por su origen verbal, ese núcleo recibirá complementos típicos del verbo. "pelotas" es objeto directo. En efecto, podemos decir: Atraparlas es divertido.

Del mismo modo, a pesar de encontrarse dentro del sujeto, podemos agregarle un sinfín de complementos que pertenecen típicamente al predicado, en cuyo caso será más habitual posponer el sujeto, a fin de no desbalancear la oración:

Es divertido atrapar pelotas sin parar entre los árboles en un día de invierno.

Observemos que no sólo tenemos un objeto directo que "modifica" al núcleo "atrapar", sino tres complementos circunstanciales, de modo, lugar y tiempo, respectivamente.