# Cuales son los usos de -ing?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, infinitivo, gerundio, tiempos-verbales-progresivos

El uso de -ing en español, cuando no se esta usando como presente o pasado progresivo, se expresa con el infinitivo:

> El comer sano es importante. 
>   [EN] *Eating healthy is important*.

Pero qué pasa por ejemplo con usos como:

> Los niños se entretienen jugando y nadando.

vs

> Los niños se entretienen al jugar y nadar.

¿Sufre el significado al usar "jugar y nadar"?

Comment: no entiendo la duda, puedes explicarte un poco más?

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando por la relación entre el gerundio en español y el gerundio en inglés?

Answer (score 2):

El primer ejemplo es un infinitivo (comer). El infinitivo en español puede realizar funciones de sustantivo. Consulta [Qué función sintáctica tiene “atrapar” en la frase “Atrapar pelotas es divertido”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19342/5481).

El gerundio es una forma no personal del verbo. Sus terminaciones son: *-ando* y *-iendo* (ejemplos: jug**ando**, nad**ando**, com**iendo**, r**iendo**). El gerundio es una forma verbal con valor *adverbial*. No posee valor *adjetivo* ni *sustantivo*.

El gerundio se usa correctamente cuando expresa una acción simultánea o anterior al verbo<sup>1</sup>

> Desayunaba *leyendo* la novela. (acción simultánea al verbo)
>
> Habiendo *hablado* con su novia salió apurado. (gerundio compuesto: expresa una acción anterior al verbo -anterior a la acción del verbo salir)
>
> Mi madre me miró *sonriendo*.

En el caso de tu ejemplo "jugando y nadando" son **acciones simultáneas** a "entretener(se)".

`¿Sufre el significado al usar "jugar y nadar"?`

Podrías decir

> *Jugar* y *nadar* entretiene a los niños

En este caso "jugar" y "nadar' tendrían la función de sustantivos (y no serían acciones simultáneas al verbo). No pasa con el gerundio porque, como hemos dicho, no tiene valor de adjetivo ni sustantivo, solo valor adverbial.

El significado de la frase cambia ligeramente, y ya no se expresan acciones simultáneas o "en progreso".

---

1. El gerundio se usa **incorrectamente** cuando expresa una acción posterior al verbo principal

> Se durmió tranquilamente **despertándose** a la 8 de la mañana

Se usa como adjetivo

> Se perdió un bolso **conteniendo** materiales escolares.

o se usan dos gerundios a la vez

> **Estando corriendo** me llamaron de emergencia.